# Are these IBM XPages requests valid HTTP requests?

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, httprequest, xpages, lotus-domino

My errors are becoming more and more ridiculous every minute. I now have the ultimate problem with my reverse proxy.

An IIS8 reverse proxy should send all requests coming for

```
(.*)\.nsf(.*)
(.*)\.ibmxspres(.*)
```

to the IBM Domino http server - which it does, at least for basic requests that every third-grader deems valid.

But now, guess what happens when I open the following "URL" (a) on the IBM Domino HTTP directly and (b) via IIS8 Reverse proxy:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/css/2Ojcore.css&2Ojdojo.css&2OldefaultTheme.css&2OldojoTheme.css&@Da&@Ib&@Th&@Ti&2TgxspSF.css&Wdojoroot/dojo/resources/dojo.css&Wdojoroot/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/claro/EnhancedGrid.css&Wdojoroot/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/tundra/EnhancedGrid.css&Wdojoroot/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/EnhancedGrid_rtl.css&Wdojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css&Wdojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css&Wdojoroot/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css.css
```

**Is this an URL that every HTTP server should be able to handle?**

If yes, why isn't IIS routing them through, although they match the rule?
If no, why is IBM using such non-standard HTTP requests, and can I change this behaviour somewhere?

Comment: There are non-escaped slashes in the query arguments, so no, this is not a valid url in a strict sense. However every decent http server and client should be able to handle this. I suggest you ask MicroSoft why their server behaves unexpected. After all you most likely have payed for support from them :-)

Comment: @arkascha Doesn't the query arguments start at the first `?`?

Comment: Yes, indeed the first `?` separates the query arguments form the base url. I see your point here, this detail slipped my look. Indeed this makes things even more invalid :-) Looks to me like this is the result of some attempt to "implode" query arguments that got attached to a url not meant for that.

Comment: @arkascha I asked because there is no `?` in the uri I posted - so for a standards-conforming web server, there would be no query arguments in it. But are `&` allowed in the base uri?

Comment: The funny thing is that the lotus notes http server handles this malformed url indeed very well... :(

Comment: No, you are right about this. I meant to confirm that issue with my last comment. Sorry if I was unclear in that.

Comment: As said: decent http servers and clients implement some robustness towards handling invalid urls. :-)

Comment: Alexander, the application in question has been set to minify the CSS (and JS) using the option to "Use runtime optimized JavaScript and CSS resources". You can remove this option (which improves performance) until you have found a solution to the issue.

Comment: @arkascha: Could you please give some details about the RFC which explains that the given URI is invalid? I can't find any problems...

Comment: @Alexander: The URI is RFC compliant and not malformed / invalid. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986